# Need a cross platform tool for UI Testing

Tags: testing, cross-platform, ui-automation, seetest

I want to write code in a platform that supports multi-device capabilities for UI automation. 
Can I use Selenium? Does Selenium support this? I can see that Winium for Windows and Appium for Android and ios are available.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

> automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.

But you can use [SeeTest Studio](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/SeeTest+Automation) for Automation of

- iOS
- Android
- Windows Phone

If you keep the [Write-once test-everywhere](http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/java-write-once-test-everywhere) pattern, you can just swap  between the captured elements in the [Object Repository](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Objects+Repository). This way you will have unified test flow, but different devices.